I am using IonicRouteStrategy and I want to preserve the state of the component without destroying it
I have several routes. After loading on the main page, I expect that the component will not change its state and will live even after switching to other pages. But if you do not load on the home page and go to it. Then after leaving it, it is completely destroyed.  I use ionic and its routing policy.
 ionViewDidLeave() {
   console.log('dead')
    this.navigationService.modalEventShowOpen.next(false)
    this.destroy$.next()
    this.destroy$.complete()
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // отписываемся от всех подписок
    console.log('dead')
    this.destroy$.next()
    this.destroy$.complete()
  }

I checked it through ngOnDestroy, and through ionViewDidLeave.  And each time the component died. I expected him to keep his condition.

There are several ways: You can create a custom RouteReuseStrategy to cache components or Using a Service for State Management.

I tried, but ioniс wouldn't let me add a custom strategy.
